# Can help me with my C code?

Tags: c

I'm supposed to make a program which allows me to do this calculation:
-5+10-20+40-80+160

I've done this so far:

```
const int START = -5, LIMIT = 160;

int somme = 0;  
int terme = START;

do {
    somme += terme;

    terme = terme * 2;

    terme = -terme;

} while(terme <= LIMIT);

printf ("equals %d\n\n", somme);
```

But when I run it it shows -215 and of course it's not the correct answer. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: `} while(abs(terme) <= LIMIT);`

Comment: Add a `printf` at the bottom of your loop to show the values of `somme` and `terme`. That should help.

Comment: Why would that not be the correct answer?

Comment: I have no clue what your code *should* do. Please read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) on non-english variable names.

Comment: The correct answer should be 105 (-5+10-20+40-80+160) I've changed and now it's better:

do {
 somme += terme;
 terme = terme * -2;
 
} while(terme < LIMIT);


but now the answer is -55, for some reason it won't do the 160 that's left.

Comment: You get -55 because you use < rather than <=. The term 160 never gets added to the sum. Use the suggestion @BLUEPIXY gave you.

Comment: THANKS!! Now it's working I should review how abs work. I didn't know that function.

Comment: @Sandra: `abs()` function or macro (#define) as in example below does not matter - use `while` instead of `do..while`

Comment: `int abs(int)` in `stdlib.h`, return the absolute value of the argument.

Comment: thanks BLUEPIXY!, for me as a beginner is very useful to know these functions. I'd give you some points but I don't know how to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use absulute value of `terme` in condition of your loop, that better have to be PRE-CONDITION while:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define ABS(X) (X>=0)?(X):(-X)

int main()
{
    const int START = -5, LIMIT = 160;

    int somme = 0;  
    int terme = START;

    while( ABS(terme) <= LIMIT )
    {
        somme += terme;

        terme = terme * 2;

        terme = -terme;
    } 
    printf ("equals %d\n\n", somme);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a calculation like this, you should look at the expression more carefully. What you want is:

-5+10-20+40-80+160

= 5*(- 1 + 2 - 4 + 8 - 16 + 32)

= 5*( (-1)^1*(2^0) + (-1)^1*(2^1) + (-1)^1*(2^2) + (-1)^1*(2^3) + (-1)^1*(2^4) + (-1)^1*(2^5) )

where in C terms, a^b is equivalent to `pow(a,b)`

= 5 * sum over i ((-1)^(i+1) * 2^i  )    where i goes from 0 to 5

Do you think that it would be easier to iterate over a variable `i` in a `for` loop? Ill leave this as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

another cool way:

```
const int START = -5, LIMIT = 160;

int somme = 0;  
for(int terme = START; (terme<LIMIT && (-terme)<LIMIT)||(printf("equals //
                      %d\n\n",somme),0); terme = -(terme*2)){
somme += terme;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! knowing as much as I can for me as a beginner is essential.